# No applicable method for mutate?

Tags: r

Currently trying to use sample R code and implement it into my own
Sample code goes like this:

```r
syn_data <- syn_data %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(gender = factor(gender,
                                labels = c("female", "male")))
```

My code goes:

```r
data <- data %>%
    dplyr::mutate(condition = factor(condition,
                                labels = c("Fixed Ratio 6", "Variable Ratio 6", "Fixed Interval 8", "Variable Interval 8")))
```

Getting this error:

```
Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "character"
```

Edit:

```
categorical. Reinforcement schedule the rat has been assigned to: 0 = 'Fixed Ratio 6'; 1 = 'Variable Ratio 6'; 2 = 'Fixed Interval 8'; 3 = 'Variable Interval 8'.
```

Data (sample right, mine left)

[image: data]

Comment: Please provide a sample of how your data looks like. Otherwise this is hard to tell

Comment: could you provide `str(data)´:

Comment: The error is telling you that `mutate()` expects `data` to be a dataframe, whereas it’s apparently just a character vector.

Answer (score 5):

The cause of your problem is that `data` is not a `data.frame`, which is the required class for the first argument of `mutate`. If you change it to a data.frame, your code works.

For example:

```
tap_data <- data.frame(rat_id = 1:4, condition = c(0,1,2,3))
tap_data <- tap_data %>% mutate(condition = factor(condition,
                                labels = c("Fixed Ratio 6", "Variable Ratio 6", 
                                           "Fixed Interval 8", "Variable Interval 8")))
tap_data
#     rat_id           condition
# 1      1       Fixed Ratio 6
# 2      2    Variable Ratio 6
# 3      3    Fixed Interval 8
# 4      4 Variable Interval 8
```

To check if an object is a data.frame, you can use `is.data.frame()`. You can check for some other classes with similar syntax, such as `is.factor()`.

```
is.data.frame(tap_data)
#[1] TRUE

is.data.frame(tap_data$condition)
# [1] FALSE

is.factor(tap_data$condition)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer above, you can convert the matrix or array to a data frame as follows:

```
data <- data %>%
    as.data.frame(.) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(condition = factor(condition,
                                labels = c("Fixed Ratio 6", "Variable Ratio 6", "Fixed Interval 8", "Variable Interval 8")))
```

These `dplyr` functions are set to handle data frames only, therefore, you need to check if the data structure you are working on is of a data-frame class.