# Imputing missing values in R (NO2 in different stations)

Tags: r, missing-data

I want to replace the missing value with the average of past years on the same date.

I think for this it is worth using the dplyr package from R's tidyverse to group the data by month and day. How can I conduct mean imputation on a subset of data?

```
DATA <- read.csv('DateCaratNO2.csv')
DATA <- as.data.frame(DATA)
DATA$Full.Data <- as.POSIXct(DATA$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
DATA$day <- format(DATA$Full.Data, "%d")
DATA$month <- format(DATA$Full.Data, "%m")
DATA$year <- format(DATA$Full.Data, "%Y")
attach(DATA)
library(dplyr)
df <- DATA %>% mutate(day = lubridate::floor_date(Full.Data, "day"),
                      month = lubridate::floor_date(Full.Data, "month")) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(day, month, ID) %>%
  mutate(NO2 = replace_na(NO2, mean(NO2, na.rm=TRUE)))
```

I need to replace the missing value with the average value for the same day and month for a specific station. Any help is appreciated!

The `dput` from the data can be found here:

```
structure(list(ID = c("IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", 
"IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", 
"IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", 
"IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", 
"IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", 
"IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", 
"IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", 
"IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", 
"IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", 
"IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", 
"IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", 
"IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", 
"IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", 
"IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", 
"IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", 
"IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", 
"IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", 
"IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", 
"IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", 
"IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", 
"IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", 
"IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", 
"IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", 
"IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", 
"IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", 
"IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", 
"IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", 
"IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", 
"IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", 
"IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", 
"IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", 
"IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", 
"IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", 
"IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", 
"IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", 
"IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", 
"IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", 
"IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", 
"IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1940A", 
"IT1940A", "IT1940A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", 
"IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", 
"IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", 
"IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", 
"IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", 
"IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", 
"IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", 
"IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", 
"IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", 
"IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", 
"IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", 
"IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", 
"IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", 
"IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", 
"IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", 
"IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", 
"IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", 
"IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", 
"IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", 
"IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", 
"IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", 
"IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", 
"IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", 
"IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", 
"IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", 
"IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", 
"IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", 
"IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", 
"IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", 
"IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", 
"IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", 
"IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", 
"IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", 
"IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", 
"IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", 
"IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", 
"IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", 
"IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", 
"IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", "IT1938A", 
"IT1938A", "IT1938A"), date = c("2/1/2015", "2/2/2015", "2/3/2015", 
"2/4/2015", "2/5/2015", "2/6/2015", "2/7/2015", "2/8/2015", "2/9/2015", 
"2/10/2015", "2/11/2015", "2/12/2015", "2/13/2015", "2/14/2015", 
"2/15/2015", "2/16/2015", "2/17/2015", "2/18/2015", "2/19/2015", 
"2/20/2015", "2/21/2015", "2/22/2015", "2/23/2015", "2/24/2015", 
"2/25/2015", "2/26/2015", "2/27/2015", "2/28/2015", "2/1/2016", 
"2/2/2016", "2/3/2016", "2/4/2016", "2/5/2016", "2/6/2016", "2/7/2016", 
"2/8/2016", "2/9/2016", "2/10/2016", "2/11/2016", "2/12/2016", 
"2/13/2016", "2/14/2016", "2/15/2016", "2/16/2016", "2/17/2016", 
"2/18/2016", "2/19/2016", "2/20/2016", "2/21/2016", "2/22/2016", 
"2/23/2016", "2/24/2016", "2/25/2016", "2/26/2016", "2/27/2016", 
"2/28/2016", "2/29/2016", "1/1/2017", "1/2/2017", "1/3/2017", 
"1/4/2017", "1/5/2017", "1/6/2017", "1/7/2017", "1/8/2017", "1/9/2017", 
"1/10/2017", "1/11/2017", "1/12/2017", "1/13/2017", "1/14/2017", 
"1/15/2017", "1/16/2017", "1/17/2017", "1/18/2017", "1/19/2017", 
"1/20/2017", "1/21/2017", "1/22/2017", "1/23/2017", "1/24/2017", 
"1/25/2017", "1/26/2017", "1/27/2017", "1/28/2017", "1/29/2017", 
"1/30/2017", "1/31/2017", "2/1/2018", "2/2/2018", "2/3/2018", 
"2/4/2018", "2/5/2018", "2/6/2018", "2/7/2018", "2/8/2018", "2/9/2018", 
"2/10/2018", "2/11/2018", "2/12/2018", "2/13/2018", "2/14/2018", 
"2/15/2018", "2/16/2018", "2/17/2018", "2/18/2018", "2/19/2018", 
"2/20/2018", "2/21/2018", "2/22/2018", "2/23/2018", "2/24/2018", 
"2/25/2018", "2/26/2018", "2/27/2018", "2/28/2018", "1/1/2019", 
"1/2/2019", "1/3/2019", "1/4/2019", "1/5/2019", "1/6/2019", "1/7/2019", 
"1/8/2019", "1/9/2019", "1/10/2019", "1/11/2019", "1/12/2019", 
"1/13/2019", "1/14/2019", "1/15/2019", "1/16/2019", "1/17/2019", 
"1/18/2019", "1/19/2019", "1/20/2019", "1/21/2019", "1/22/2019", 
"1/23/2019", "1/24/2019", "1/25/2019", "1/26/2019", "1/27/2019", 
"1/28/2019", "1/29/2019", "1/30/2019", "1/31/2019", "2/1/2019", 
"2/2/2019", "2/3/2019", "2/4/2019", "2/5/2019", "2/6/2019", "2/7/2019", 
"2/8/2019", "2/9/2019", "2/10/2019", "2/11/2019", "2/12/2019", 
"2/13/2019", "2/14/2019", "2/15/2019", "2/16/2019", "2/17/2019", 
"2/18/2019", "2/19/2019", "2/20/2019", "2/21/2019", "2/22/2019", 
"2/23/2019", "2/24/2019", "2/25/2019", "2/26/2019", "2/27/2019", 
"2/28/2019", "1/1/2020", "1/2/2020", "1/3/2020", "1/4/2020", 
"1/5/2020", "1/6/2020", "1/7/2020", "1/8/2020", "1/9/2020", "1/10/2020", 
"1/11/2020", "1/12/2020", "1/13/2020", "1/14/2020", "1/15/2020", 
"1/16/2020", "1/17/2020", "1/18/2020", "1/19/2020", "1/20/2020", 
"1/21/2020", "1/22/2020", "1/23/2020", "1/24/2020", "1/25/2020", 
"1/26/2020", "1/27/2020", "1/28/2020", "1/29/2020", "1/30/2020", 
"1/31/2020", "2/1/2021", "2/2/2021", "2/3/2021", "2/4/2021", 
"2/5/2021", "2/6/2021", "2/7/2021", "2/8/2021", "2/9/2021", "2/10/2021", 
"2/11/2021", "2/12/2021", "2/13/2021", "2/14/2021", "2/15/2021", 
"2/16/2021", "2/17/2021", "2/18/2021", "2/19/2021", "2/20/2021", 
"2/21/2021", "2/22/2021", "2/23/2021", "2/24/2021", "2/25/2021", 
"2/26/2021", "2/27/2021", "2/28/2021", "2/1/2015", "2/2/2015", 
"2/3/2015", "2/4/2015", "2/5/2015", "2/6/2015", "2/7/2015", "2/8/2015", 
"2/9/2015", "2/10/2015", "2/11/2015", "2/12/2015", "2/13/2015", 
"2/14/2015", "2/15/2015", "2/16/2015", "2/17/2015", "2/18/2015", 
"2/19/2015", "2/20/2015", "2/21/2015", "2/22/2015", "2/23/2015", 
"2/24/2015", "2/25/2015", "2/26/2015", "2/27/2015", "2/28/2015", 
"2/1/2016", "2/2/2016", "2/3/2016", "2/4/2016", "2/5/2016", "2/6/2016", 
"2/7/2016", "2/8/2016", "2/9/2016", "2/10/2016", "2/11/2016", 
"2/12/2016", "2/13/2016", "2/14/2016", "2/15/2016", "2/16/2016", 
"2/17/2016", "2/18/2016", "2/19/2016", "2/20/2016", "2/21/2016", 
"2/22/2016", "2/23/2016", "2/24/2016", "2/25/2016", "2/26/2016", 
"2/27/2016", "2/28/2016", "2/29/2016", "1/1/2017", "1/2/2017", 
"1/3/2017", "1/4/2017", "1/5/2017", "1/6/2017", "1/7/2017", "1/8/2017", 
"1/9/2017", "1/10/2017", "1/11/2017", "1/12/2017", "1/13/2017", 
"1/14/2017", "1/15/2017", "1/16/2017", "1/17/2017", "1/18/2017", 
"1/19/2017", "1/20/2017", "1/21/2017", "1/22/2017", "1/23/2017", 
"1/24/2017", "1/25/2017", "1/26/2017", "1/27/2017", "1/28/2017", 
"1/29/2017", "1/30/2017", "1/31/2017", "2/1/2018", "2/2/2018", 
"2/3/2018", "2/4/2018", "2/5/2018", "2/6/2018", "2/7/2018", "2/8/2018", 
"2/9/2018", "2/10/2018", "2/11/2018", "2/12/2018", "2/13/2018", 
"2/14/2018", "2/15/2018", "2/16/2018", "2/17/2018", "2/18/2018", 
"2/19/2018", "2/20/2018", "2/21/2018", "2/22/2018", "2/23/2018", 
"2/24/2018", "2/25/2018", "2/26/2018", "2/27/2018", "2/28/2018", 
"1/1/2019", "1/2/2019", "1/3/2019", "1/4/2019", "1/5/2019", "1/6/2019", 
"1/7/2019", "1/8/2019", "1/9/2019", "1/10/2019", "1/11/2019", 
"1/12/2019", "1/13/2019", "1/14/2019", "1/15/2019", "1/16/2019", 
"1/17/2019", "1/18/2019", "1/19/2019", "1/20/2019", "1/21/2019", 
"1/22/2019", "1/23/2019", "1/24/2019", "1/25/2019", "1/26/2019", 
"1/27/2019", "1/28/2019", "1/29/2019", "1/30/2019", "1/31/2019", 
"2/1/2019", "2/2/2019", "2/3/2019", "2/4/2019", "2/5/2019", "2/6/2019", 
"2/7/2019", "2/8/2019", "2/9/2019", "2/10/2019", "2/11/2019", 
"2/12/2019", "2/13/2019", "2/14/2019", "2/15/2019", "2/16/2019", 
"2/17/2019", "2/18/2019", "2/19/2019", "2/20/2019", "2/21/2019", 
"2/22/2019", "2/23/2019", "2/24/2019", "2/25/2019", "2/26/2019", 
"2/27/2019", "2/28/2019", "1/1/2020", "1/2/2020", "1/3/2020", 
"1/4/2020", "1/5/2020", "1/6/2020", "1/7/2020", "1/8/2020", "1/9/2020", 
"1/10/2020", "1/11/2020", "1/12/2020", "1/13/2020", "1/14/2020", 
"1/15/2020", "1/16/2020", "1/17/2020", "1/18/2020", "1/19/2020", 
"1/20/2020", "1/21/2020", "1/22/2020", "1/23/2020", "1/24/2020", 
"1/25/2020", "1/26/2020", "1/27/2020", "1/28/2020", "1/29/2020", 
"1/30/2020", "1/31/2020", "2/1/2021", "2/2/2021", "2/3/2021", 
"2/4/2021", "2/5/2021", "2/6/2021", "2/7/2021", "2/8/2021", "2/9/2021", 
"2/10/2021", "2/11/2021", "2/12/2021", "2/13/2021", "2/14/2021", 
"2/15/2021", "2/16/2021", "2/17/2021", "2/18/2021", "2/19/2021", 
"2/20/2021", "2/21/2021", "2/22/2021", "2/23/2021", "2/24/2021", 
"2/25/2021", "2/26/2021", "2/27/2021", "2/28/2021"), NO2 = c(8.494022, 
10.270843, 20.854183, 26.973156, 17.957637, 14.908667, 16.15965, 
11.995295, 8.860629, 10.035246, 20.141964, 22.327379, 21.02741, 
24.465761, 16.538571, 16.556504, 4.783193, 7.59238, 19.161681, 
22.677657, 15.586068, NA, NA, NA, 16.631454, 11.29906, 14.864193, 
16.420849, 14.104021, 18.786681, 16.8078, 5.788044, 4.648989, 
15.276459, 6.557777, 14.57682, 21.385529, 7.954627, 9.436122, 
9.503997, 6.562462, 9.555659, 14.54271, 11.293801, 9.99976, 5.034411, 
6.153122, 3.590124, 3.350876, 15.858318, 11.843004, 3.834344, 
13.858539, 7.778169, 8.614458, 2.18815, 14.864767, 23.718167, 
22.192393, 21.003893, 11.270417, 12.869576, 5.541511, 6.065571, 
8.600884, 15.744785, 17.657224, 19.806599, 21.258571, 20.145979, 
9.321535, 12.00277, 15.655933, 17.461837, 24.439565, 16.996054, 
13.463386, 4.692335, 2.42172, 9.528777, 8.088544, 20.124756, 
17.19798, 17.549501, 17.667262, 10.398431, 20.365667, 26.515232, 
13.012708, 7.710178, 6.731884, 6.873468, 13.216107, 8.248941, 
12.667134, 7.967476, 13.450384, 4.469243, 6.016051, 20.221312, 
9.978077, 8.125063, 6.054654, 17.886531, 16.911314, 14.872607, 
18.379769, 13.280178, 13.173737, 16.163359, 7.180439, 7.067153, 
5.78097, 9.115078, 11.401236, 13.672157, 7.67733, 9.121578, 9.53306, 
9.169626, 10.399597, 9.929665, 13.432182, 21.290884, 11.990955, 
7.629396, 11.871206, 7.8844, 13.096837, 17.530286, 15.16868, 
23.066559, 24.500176, 21.301399, 19.780404, 10.435753, 17.164999, 
10.730105, 10.39671, 21.078079, 10.896736, 12.381213, 17.814773, 
10.77259, 12.325191, 14.441106, 13.372432, 12.20334, 2.267116, 
7.004822, 6.484815, 6.160732, 11.205868, 17.221174, 12.932672, 
15.424868, 13.584568, 9.045232, 9.253143, 4.746712, 5.356391, 
7.956635, 15.78769, 15.203057, 21.611717, 13.938919, 10.338719, 
14.906831, 12.02256, 8.323146, 5.962648, 12.607288, 8.366664, 
11.722606, 13.118021, 13.167657, 23.943211, 15.73205, NA, NA, 
NA, 19.458806, 13.905096, 22.780715, 28.207544, 16.330735, 10.908304, 
13.027756, 18.055168, 18.981838, 14.758766, 22.892374, 15.730101, 
4.159135, 6.782227, 8.725889, 16.589754, 16.98659, 14.466077, 
9.835424, 5.603747, 7.533586, 7.258124, 3.757233, 6.975397, 16.506639, 
22.993903, 22.146121, 32.453523, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 8.874777, 5.274195, 8.771376, NA, 13.485412, 21.698904, 
27.922464, 16.498973, 28.762024, 23.60364, 24.60113, 27.767211, 
31.555646, 31.960224, 12.792771, 11.874074, 25.523096, 36.005253, 
37.642116, 43.185004, 26.004919, 30.18264, 25.999374, NA, 32.056592, 
37.521471, 38.501752, 43.199343, 47.116269, 39.203263, 45.309426, 
26.376231, 25.090029, 35.950189, 33.532655, 28.406965, 24.936877, 
32.878943, 26.889793, 24.207449, 31.056998, 29.679594, 36.303335, 
28.31691, 35.54293, 18.791613, 17.165094, 31.426778, 26.191531, 
33.661524, NA, 18.94205, 8.852177, 20.852655, 22.10272, 17.050833, 
18.940024, NA, NA, NA, NA, 22.335409, 23.47458, 12.399243, 23.636525, 
NA, 21.434094, 22.799834, 23.083384, 17.963889, 9.915422, 20.821297, 
35.158618, 35.247528, 33.416598, 35.369512, 34.734347, 40.436504, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 36.207926, 33.685805, 30.957001, 
37.630453, 42.27948, 46.808245, 31.737096, 53.81515, 18.27784, 
33.830545, 50.393628, 42.016389, 36.003148, 36.643481, 47.376107, 
36.050758, 26.756718, 19.165313, 8.837838, 18.859527, 32.150087, 
24.903609, 16.42232, 28.227237, 32.079918, 27.3481, NA, 33.219278, 
33.551203, 35.606984, 38.398312, 45.264114, 41.581028, 24.478762, 
50.790748, 32.137279, 39.643216, 28.691853, 42.126903, 33.707412, 
27.494751, 26.748115, 38.457202, 37.951861, 17.364936, 32.06137, 
26.519822, 41.503974, 46.908624, 30.394106, 47.184144, 35.195138, 
39.95927, 41.872991, 38.210744, 27.324773, 30.350131, 52.469295, 
34.62326, 32.508014, 33.325587, 29.8272, 31.795985, NA, 51.978294, 
38.143252, 29.89106, 42.116386, 36.054773, 32.849115, 18.242602, 
18.520913, 29.982071, 26.920768, 27.383854, 21.16106, 9.234787, 
NA, 36.617475, 12.935865, 18.385505, 25.670893, 26.499172, 23.917398, 
18.786183, 8.155483, 13.224367, 4.103037, 22.595824, 28.268346, 
26.41122, 17.739975, 26.06706, 24.139574, 28.397405, 30.879564, 
24.112995, 10.538676, 9.012384, 14.210404, 24.614131, 33.060392, 
24.914316, 33.322334, 27.921317, 35.113113, 26.507393, 14.22918, 
7.30602, 37.749187, 43.352686, 34.664751, 33.116411, 40.646825, 
32.890795, 30.315907, 37.905017, 43.562624, 40.983335, 28.682102, 
34.585785, 26.711978, 33.635901, 32.167869, 39.401156, 41.840677, 
46.413608, 31.613008, 28.768333, 27.468747, 19.921701, 16.148044, 
23.349917, 19.946367, 22.412272, 27.136632, 17.069591, 21.201786, 
35.533755, 35.117128, 25.738005, 20.21309, 12.068008, 10.685154, 
24.855044, 18.835436, 12.114451, 6.274859, 9.588431, 18.601217, 
27.243322, 27.039121, 28.688985, 27.590541, 15.86111, 28.251711, 
27.363969, 22.524697, 34.540087, 32.924065, 14.335373, 15.010271
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -468L))
```

Comment: Whats the issue with this code? Do you get an error as output? Which one?

Comment: When I do 'write.csv', the missing value get NA value. That is, the replacement of the average does not pass.

Comment: Could you share a dataset to reproduce your problem and the part of the code in which you use `write.csv()`?

Comment: [enter image description here][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYGYZ.png
write.csv(df,"C:\\Users\\....\\NO2.csv", row.names = FALSE)

Comment: Sharing an image is not helpful. Get a subset with the minimal number of samples to reproduce your issue and use `dput()`, copy the output of the function and paste it in your edited post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what you want (with tidyverse and lubridate)

```
data %>% 
  mutate(
    date = as.POSIXct(date, format = "%m/%d/%Y"),
    day = day(date),
    month = month(date),
    year = year(date)
  ) %>% 
  group_by(day, month, ID) %>% 
  mutate(
    aveNO2 = mean(NO2,na.rm=TRUE)
  ) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(
    comment = case_when(is.na(NO2) ~ "ave used"),
    NO2 = case_when(is.na(NO2) ~ aveNO2,
                    TRUE ~ NO2)
  )
```

Comment: I'm getting an error message. 'Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "c('POSIXct', 'POSIXt')"'

Comment: What do you get if you do `str(data)`?

Comment: You should check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71395031/no-applicable-method-for-mutate
The problem is probably with `read.csv()`.  It is reading the date column in a weird way maybe.
When I tested my solution I had your data as a tibble, but it also works with a dataframe.

Comment: ''data.frame': 49458 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ ID       : chr  "IT2028A" "IT2028A" "IT2028A" "IT2028A" ...
 $ longitude: num  15.6 15.6 15.6 15.6 15.6 ...
 $ latitude : num  38.1 38.1 38.1 38.1 38.1 ...
 $ date     : chr  "9/1/2014" "9/2/2014" "9/3/2014" "9/4/2014" ...
 $ NO2      : num  24.2 13.6 20.1 21.2 18.5 ...'

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error so it is a bit tricky. Try to use `date = mdy(date)` in `mutate` instead of `as.POSIXct`.
My guess is that there is something weird somewhere in your date column that did not appear in the sample you provided. Just to be sure, did you load the tidyverse and lubridate library?

Comment: I need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but I appreciate you for your help and support.

Answer (score 0):

To do the mean of grouped data I would use summarise:

```
group_by(day, month, ID) %>%
  summarise(
    average = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Is this helping?

Comment: Looks like the data is sampled in hours or less, so summarising everything you are just returning 1 measure per day

Comment: Nope. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

#### Imputation Method

Another option if you want to provide a more realistic imputation is using the `mice` package, which uses a much more effective method for imputing missing data. For the example I show here, I pool the data into a complete dataset. If you were to run an inferential test on this data, it would be invalid due to Rubin's Rules for imputation, so you would need to run this data with the regression, t-test, etc. before pooling the data. If you are just concerned with having realistic descriptive data this is not an issue.

#### How to Perform

Here is how you achieve this. First load the `mice` package for imputation and the `tidyverse` for plotting later.

```
#### Load Library ####
library(mice)
library(tidyverse)
```

You first impute the data. Typically the default is 5 imputations, which I have designated specifically here. I have named your dput as `data`:

```
#### Impute Data Five Times ####
set.seed(123) # to reproduce results
imp <- mice(data = data,
            m=5)
```

Then we can check how the imputations performed by using these two plots:

```
#### Check Imputations ####
plot(imp) # should be scattered
densityplot(imp) # shows densities used for each imputation
```

Finally, you can pool the imputed data into a complete dataset without NA values.

```
#### Pool Data Together ####
complete.data <- complete(imp)
```

#### Plot Complete Data

As an example, here is the NO2 data, which now has no NA values, as they have been imputed already.

```
#### Plot Imputed NO2 Data ####
complete.data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=NO2))+
  geom_density(fill="steelblue",
               alpha = .4,
               size=1)+
  labs(y="Density",
       title = "Density of Imputed NO2 Data")+
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

#### Reference

Here are the `mice` vignettes if you want to learn more about this method:

https://www.gerkovink.com/miceVignettes/